# C++ Inheritance Enum

Tags: c++, inheritance

In C++ I have a base class A for example which looks like this:

```
class A {
    enum type {B, C, D, E};
    ....
    ....
}
```

For each enumerated type I have another class which is derived from the base A. 
For example I have one class like this:

```
class B : public A {
    int x;
    ....
    ....
};
```

My question is: With an A object and from it for which I know that is type B so it corresponds to class B is it possible to have access to variable x for example and if yes how? I know that it is a bit tricky to gain access to derived class from base but I suppose that is something different not like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an `A *a` or `A &a` and know for certain that it actually points/refers to an object of type `B`, you can use a cast:

```
A *a = ...;
B *b = static_cast<B*>(a);
```

or

```
A &a = ...;
B &b = static_cast<B&>(a);
```

Comment: I would suggest `dynamic_cast`, better be safe.

Comment: Nope, it just makes use of runtime type information to make sure a is actually an instance of B. The other direction (upcast) would be checked at compile-time.

Comment: @Marius Use `dynamic_cast` if you *don't know* whether the cast can succeed (or if you're in a complex hierarchy and `static_cast` cannot be applied). If you *know* (i.e. you could `assert()`) that the cast succeeds, use `static_cast` (or perhaps [`boost::polymorphic_downcast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/conversion/cast.htm#Polymorphic_cast), to actually get the `assert()`). Also, you need a virtual member for `dynamic_cast` to work.

Comment: I agree, using a debug-build `assert()` together with `static_cast` would be the optimal solution for performance critical code. I however tend to use `dynamic_cast` in other cases because, well, if you ever had a bug where you cast the wrong class, you'll know. Also, the OpenSSL team also 'knew' the size of the payload it has to send back to the client right? (ok thats totally unrelated but if we have such safety features in C++ why don't make use of them).